# Oracle Datapump impdp Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, oracle, ioctl, datapump, impdp

i had an error while exporting my schema and then import it into a new database.
My Exporting System is an Oracle Linux 7 with 19c Database and the importing system is Oracle Linux 8 with 21c XE. When i import the schema with impdp i receive the error:

```
impdp system/password@localhost/xepdb1 full=y directory=data_pump_dir dumpfile=test.dmp
```

> ORA-39001: ivalid argument 
> ORA-39000: incorrect specification of dump file
> ORA-31619: invalid dump file "opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/CC96F85...01/test.dmp"
> ORA-27072: File-I/O-Error
> Linux-x86_64 Error: 25: Inappropriate ioctl for device
> Additional information: 4 
> Additional information: 1

Comment: show us which `impdp` command are you executing ? It looks like you either don't have a database directory for that location, or the privileges are not right. Although innapropiate ioctl for device implies that the datapump file is corrupted

Comment: how did you transfer the dmp file from the source server to the target server ?

Comment: transfered via USB-Stick

Comment: did you create the directory `data_pump_dir` ? if so, how did you do it ?

Comment: No the data_pump_dir was already there

Comment: do you have space in the file system?

Comment: yes. i also checked the tablespace 'TEMP' and resizes it to 512MB, the dmp file only has arround 100mb

Comment: run this command  `df -h /opt/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/CC96F85...01/` and let us know how much space do you have there

Comment: I believe you have the datapump file corrupted. That might happen when the transfers are done without using binary mode

Comment: YES. I checked the dmp file and saw it has 0kb. So it was corrupted. I dont know why. I exported again and now the impdp works !!!

Comment: I will put this as an answer, please accept it, as then others can benefit from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments

When you got the error `Inappropriate ioctl for device` , Oracle is not responsible, as the error is coming from Linux.

Most of the times due to:

- The datapump file is corrupted.
- The file is not not a valid datapump file
- The datapump file is empty.